# Logical operators don't work in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, logical-operators

I must make a website with WordPress and I have to show the post in a horizontal sequence into a table of 4 columns. The problem is simple. When I put `$i != 1`, it does show the post I need but.

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()) : 
    while(have_posts()) : 
        $i++; 
        if($i!=1) : 
            $wp-query->next_post(); 
         else : 
            the_post() ;
```

I have 3 posts for training. If I change the condition by

```
($i+1) % 2 == 1.
```

It shows the first post and the third but if I put

```
($i+1) % 2 == 1 && $i=!1
```

It still shows the first and third post.

I thought of putting

```
($i+1) % 2 == 1 && ($i+1) %3 ==0
```

But it still shows the first and the third

Remark: if I put

```
($i+1) % 2 == 1 && ($i+1) %3 !=0
```

it shows the first, second and third posts.

Comment: It show all in the same column. I'm interested to have 1 post on column 1 and second post on column 2 and same rule for column 3.

Comment: no idea what you actually want to do...if you just want 4 columns in a row and want to know when to open a new row increment $i after your if function, if($i % 4) == 0 will catch the 5th -- 0 1 2 3 <b>4</b>